# Daylight savings time in Angular/Javascript Date

Tags: javascript, angular, date

I'm trying to get the datetime with daylight savings.

```
alert(new Date());
```

> Gives me Thu Apr 04 2019 12:10:42 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern
>   Daylight Time)

```
alert(new Date(2019,4,4));
```

> Gives me Sat May 04 2019 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (Australian Eastern
>   Standard Time)

Why the first result is correct and the second result is incorrect given that, today's date is actually `2019/04/04`.

Also the second result does not considers the Daylight savings time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because months in dates are 0-based (like arrays):

> **`monthIndex`**
>   Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.

[Dates in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)